# Unexpected request: GET

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to to mock backend with ngMockE2E for development purpose but having this error "Unexpected request: GET views/home.html". Also I am using ui-router from route services.Thanks

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="userApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Angular App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui-router.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/services.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <header id="header">
            <div class="logo col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
                <h1>logo</h1>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                    <li><a ui-sref="home" class="btn btn-success" ui-sref-active="btn-warning">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a ui-sref="login" class="btn btn-success" ui-sref-active="btn-warning">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a ui-sref="register" class="btn btn-success" ui-sref-active="btn-warning">Register</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="text-area col-sm-12 col-lg-8">
                <h2>Test</h2>
            </div>
        </header>
        <section id="main">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div ui-view></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer id="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <p class="text-center">Copyright </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function(ng){
var userApp =   ng.module("userApp", ["ui.router", "ngMockE2E", "ngResource", "ngCookies", "mainCtrl"]);
userApp.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$provide", function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $provide){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise( "/" );
    $provide.decorator("$httpBackend", ng.mock.e2e.$httpBackendDecorator);
    $stateProvider
        .state("login", {
            url         :   "/login",
            templateUrl :   "views/login.html",
            controller  :   "loginCtrl"
        })
        .state("register", {
            url         :   "/register",
            templateUrl :   "views/register.html",
            controller  :   "registerCtrl"
        })
        .state("home", {
            url         :   "/",
            templateUrl :   "views/home.html",
            controller  :   "homeCtrl"
        })
}]);
userApp.run([ "$httpBackend", function($httpBackend){
    var users =  [{ "id"    :   "1", "username" :   "user1@test.com", "password"    :   "user1" }];
    $httpBackend.expect("GET", "/login");
    $httpBackend.when("GET", "/login").respond(users[0]);
}]); 
})(angular);
```

Comment: I think if you change `url         :   "/",` to `url         :   "/home",` or something it won't happen. You have `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise( "/" );` and that triggers the `home` state, which in turn turns to `views/home.html`. That's what I think happens anyway :)

Comment: change `"views/home.html"` to `"/views/home.html"`, add `/` before url

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a passThrough to your views directory, so the `$httpBackend` service won't capture the request:

```
userApp.run([ "$httpBackend", function($httpBackend){
    var users =  [{ "id"    :   "1", "username" :   "user1@test.com", "password"    :   "user1" }];
    $httpBackend.expect("GET", "/login");
    $httpBackend.when("GET", "/login").respond(users[0]);

    $httpBackend.whenGET(/^views\//).passThrough(); // ignore requests to the views directory
}]);
```